# Xamarin Forms TemplateBinding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I understand XAML doesn't really have a facility to extend (inherit) one page from another, but I have seen others use ControlTemplates to achieve this effect.

I am having trouble getting a Binding to work in this scenario.  In my example, I have a base ContentPage extended by MainPage.  Also, I am using FreshMVVM, so that is why the view model is minimal as FreshMVVM handles all the plumbing of property change notifications.

When the app runs, the label should get the value "Xamarin Forms Header" initialized in the MainPageModel.

I have the fully runnable source on github [here](https://github.com/JohnLivermore/SampleXamarinApp/tree/templatebinding), but here's the code.  Can someone see what the issue is?

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<local:PageBase xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp"
             x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</local:PageBase>
```

**MainPageModel.xaml**

```
public class MainPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
{
    public MainPageModel()
    {
        LabelText = "Xamarin Forms Header";
    }

    public string LabelText { get; set; }
}
```

**PageBase.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SampleApp.PageBase">
    <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding LabelText}" />
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You need a one-two punch here: 1) template bind the label to a bindable property in your base page; 2) context bind the `LabelText` property to the "inherited" base property in your main page. Then, [IT WORKS...](https://imgur.com/ZJFSgqF).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try to change like this:

**MainPage.xaml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:PageBase xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp"
             x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage"
             LabelText ="{Binding LabelText} " 
                >
    <StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</local:PageBase>
```

**PageBase.xaml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SampleApp.PageBase">
    <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{TemplateBinding LabelText}" />
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage>
```

in your **PageBase.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class PageBase : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(PageBase), "Control Template Demo App");
    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty); }
    }
    public PageBase ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}
```

you could refer to [TemplateBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/template-binding)

Answer (score 0):

TemplateBinding doesn't bind to the View Model so whole code is fundamentally wrong, please read about the topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/template-binding

Also of note, this would likely work if you used `Binding` instead of `TemplateBinding`, but I don't think it makes sense to do that as said something is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions.  What I am trying to do is essentially inherit one page from a xaml base page.  I know that's not something officially supported in xaml, but I have seen others do it using a ControlTemplate.  And it works, but I am trying to figure out how to bind properties in the ControlTemplate to my ViewModel.  Any suggestions on how to do that?  Also, I updated my question to better clarify my goal here.

Comment: I think it should just work if you used just plain binding and no tricks like ContolTemplate. You’ve tried that?

Comment: If the PageBase.xaml uses ContentPage.Content vs a ControlTemplate, I can just include that into MainPage.xaml and it will work. But I am trying to extend PageBase with MainPage.  And at the ContentPresenter node in PageBase, that is where the MainPage contents get rendered.